# About choke in two wheeler

Tags: choke

I have purchased new scooty activa 4g in dec . I had kept on choke
around 120km and it takes so much fuel . I had filled fuel around 6.8 litre(₹500 )and it runs 147km and still have fuel around 1litre . Today  my friend told me off the choke . Lots of time I'm thinking where fuel is going on,or  not getting mileage according to prospects or actuals facts. what will happen with engine and now what should I do

Comment: Running with a choke can easily use much more fuel than normal. You are only supposed to use it until the engine has warmed up. You'll probably need to give your engine a good clean too, as it could be coked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choke is a cold starting device and should only be used until the engine is up to operating temperatures.  Depending on ambient conditions, this could be less than the first km.  Indeed in certain warm / hot conditions, the choke will barely be required at all.

Riding with the choke engaged for longer than needed will cause the engine to run rich.  That is to say it will be using more fuel than strictly needed so both performance and fuel economy will suffer.  I personally only use a choke to start an engine that's been off for at least an hour or two and will release the choke within a few minutes.  If you release the choke too early the engine may stall.  If this happens, simply re-engage the choke and start the engine again.